Which test to compare data?
I have a small (N<50) dataset with the following data



Gender (Binary option)
Parameter1 (discrete  scale 1-4)
Parameter2 (discrete scale 1-4)




Male
1
3


Female
4
4


Male
2
3


Female
3
3



And I want to study the effect of parameter 1 in the parameter 2 for each gender (If a bigger parameter 1 implies a bigger parameter 2 or vice versa and look for in which gender this correlation is bigger).
Which test should I use? I think it's not T-Student neither Chi-Square and the others I know doesn't fit my data

I would look at the Wilcoxon test to see if that fits your needs.

A literal rephrasing of your question is that you wish to analyze the $2\times 3$ contingency table whose rows are gender and columns are indicators of the relationship between the two parameters (greater, equal, or lesser).  The standard test of independence is the chi-squared test.  Could you therefore explain why you think a chi-squared test would not be appropriate?

I don't know exactly how to perform a Wilcoxon test, since I have to create just one column. And a Chi-Square I don't know exactly how to perform, maybe with this "bigger, lesser, equal" I will try.

Is that all the data, or just a snapshot if the first few rows?

Just a snapshot of all the data. The whole data has 50 rows
